# How can I check which list has the least copies of one element?

Tags: list, haskell, functional-programming, option-type

I am writing a sudoku Puzzle in Haskell and I have a [[Maybe Int]] where I need to check which of the [Maybe Int] contains the least Nothing elements. In other words, in the following code I should return 1, which is the position of the list with only two Nothing:

```
newtype Puzzle = Puzzle [[Maybe Int]]


deriving (Show, Eq) 
    example :: Puzzle
    example =    [ [Just 3, Just 6, Nothing,Nothing,Just 7, Just 1, Just 2, Nothing,Nothing]
                 , [Just 7,Just 5, Just 4, Just 9, Just 4, Nothing, Just 1, Just 8, Just 2]
                 , [Nothing,Nothing,Just 9, Just 2, Nothing,Just 4, Just 7, Nothing,Nothing]
                 , [Nothing,Nothing,Nothing,Nothing,Just 1, Just 3, Nothing,Just 2, Just 8]
                 , [Just 4, Nothing,Nothing,Just 5, Nothing,Just 2, Nothing,Nothing,Just 9]
                 , [Just 2, Just 7, Nothing,Just 4, Just 6, Nothing,Nothing,Nothing,Nothing]
                 , [Nothing,Nothing,Just 5, Just 3, Nothing,Just 8, Just 9, Nothing,Nothing]
                 , [Nothing,Just 8, Just 3, Nothing,Nothing,Nothing,Nothing,Just 6, Nothing]
                 , [Nothing,Nothing,Just 7, Just 6, Just 9, Nothing,Nothing,Just 4, Just 3]
                 ]
```

[Edit]

I already came up with a solution that does what I want, but this is very slow and inefficient so I am wondering if there is any way to write this in an algorithmically faster way.

```
nrOfBlanks :: Puzzle -> [Int]
nrOfBlanks sud = map length [ filter isNothing r | r <- rows sud] 

whichBlock :: Puzzle -> Maybe Int
whichBlock sud = 
whichBlock sud = let i = nrOfBlanks sud 
                  in head(map (\x -> case x of
                              0 -> elemIndex (foldl1' min (tail i)) i
                               _ -> elemIndex (foldl1' min i) i) i)
```

Any help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What did you try? Wha is not working?

Comment: try a combination of `countNothing = length . filter isNothing`, [`minimumBy`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:minimumBy), `indexed = zipWith [0..]` and of course `fst`

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I edited so you can see what I have so far

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want to find the (index-of) the *minimum element according to some metric* – in your case *number of `Nothing` elements*, but clearly this is a special case of a more general concept: you have some function `a -> Int` to be used on the elements of an `[a]` list. In other words, you need a helper with a signature like either

```
minIndexAccordingTo :: (a -> Int) -> [a] -> Int
```

or

```
minimumAccordingTo :: (a -> Int) -> [a] -> a
```

Something like that is always a good idea to ask Hoogle about. [The first one doesn't give useful results](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=%28a+-%3E+Int%29+-%3E+%5Ba%5D+-%3E+Int&scope=set%3Astackage), but [the second](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=%28a+-%3E+Int%29+-%3E+%5Ba%5D+-%3E+a&scope=set%3Astackage) gives as the first two suggestions

```
maximumOn :: (Partial, Ord b) => (a -> b) -> [a] -> a
minimumOn :: (Partial, Ord b) => (a -> b) -> [a] -> a
```

So, `minimumOn` is almost exactly what you need. You can import it [from the `extra` package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/extra-1.7.9/docs/Data-List-Extra.html#v:minimumOn), or here's a definition that only uses `base`:

```
import Data.List (sortOn)

minimumOn :: Ord b => (a -> b) -> [a] -> a
minimumOn f = head . sortOn f
```

Note that even though sorting is *O* (*n* · log *n*), this definition works in linear time thanks to lazyness.

Now, to use this to find an *index*, you first need to pair your elements with an index, change the metric accordingly, and then throw away the original values at the end:

```
minimumIndexOn :: Ord b => (a -> b) -> [a] -> Int
minimumIndexOn f = fst . minimumOn (f . snd) . zip [0..]
```